# Keras model.predict Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 56)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I used a `DirectoryIterator` to read images from a directory and train my model. I want to be able to verify that it works so I tried using `model.predict` on a numpy array that contains an image but I get the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 
dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 56)
```

I'm not sure what kind of shape or attributes the `DirectoryIteratory` from `flow_from_directory` has so I'm not sure what kind of input `model.predict` is expecting. This is what my code looks like

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet it seems that you're using [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) blog post. So your ConvNet's first layer is a convolutional layer, expecting the input shape to be `(150, 150)`. Let's look at your error message:

> **ValueError**: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 56)

The error says two things:

1. Your input should have 4 dimensions.
2. Got array with shape (128, 56).

So first, your numpy array shape should be in the shape of `(150, 150)` (because of your ConvNet's input shape), and you should expand the dimensions of your image to have 4 dimensions. For example (assuming your numpy array to be `x`):

```
x = x.reshape(1,150,150,3).astype('float')
x /= 255

pred = model.predict(x)
```

If you're reading the image from your hard disk, you could use the following code:

```
img = keras.preprocessing.image('image.jpg', target_size=(150,150))
x = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape(1,150,150,3).astype('float')
x /= 255

pred = model.predict(x)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed my convnet's input shape in a part of the code I didn't include. It trained successfully but I just want to be able to test it.